# DX TreeList - How to chango color of some Node

Tags: c#, colors, devexpress, nodes, treelist

i have DX treeList, it has some functionality like copy, paste, delete and so on. How to do in C# code, to change some Node color to change to some other color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look [here](http://64.237.51.130/Help/?document=XtraTreeList)

> The appearance of individual cells can
>   be customized by handling the
>   TreeList.NodeCellStyle event. This
>   event is fired for each cell before
>   it's painted. The other way to change
>   the appearance of cells is to handle
>   the TreeList.CustomDrawNodeCell event.
>   Note that changing the appearance of
>   elements via custom draw events is not
>   in effect when the control is printed
>   and exported. For more information on
>   implementing custom painting, see
>   Custom Draw

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I used TreeList.CustomDrawNodeCell event. Seems everything works good. Thanks